# Can't dodge error bars in a ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm facing an issue with a grouped barplot in R.
So I've a data.frame like this :

```
       colony      mean   type           se
139 Jan Mayen 0.5856293 global 0.0002395301
142     Papey 0.6038123 global 0.0006487672
152 Jan Mayen 0.6014371  night 0.0008216305
155     Papey 0.6276803  night 0.0050902046
165 Jan Mayen 0.6075933   boat 0.0053480205
168     Papey 0.3831395   boat 0.0355252792
```

which I plot like this:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = colony, y = mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge", aes(fill = type)) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width=0.90),aes(ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se, width=0.2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

But no matter what I try, my error bars are still stacked, I've tried different arguments for `position` like explain in other topic (`position = "dodge"` and `positions = position_dodge()`) but I never manage to have dodged erro bars.
[image]

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including the data which generates the graph [reprex].

Comment: you need a grouping variable, try adding `group = type` in the errorbar aes